# Windows 8 Metro Style App - Editing Word Documents

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, .doc

I am trying to read/write to a word (.docx) in a W8 metro app. For normal .NET Applications there are many libraries, but non of them are avaliable for Windows Store apps (e.g. Open XML SDK 2.5 is not supported in RT Apps).

The only way, it might work is via the xml document using [Windows.Data.Xml.Dom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br240819.aspx) which is going to be a lot of work. Has anyone accessed word documents with the Windows.Data.Xml.Dom (or any other library) and would like to share his code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any first hand experience, but I'd take a look at the following two alternatives before falling back to raw XML processing:

- Your best bet could be [DocIO from Syncfusion](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/winrt/controls). It's not free but the price is really reasonable considering how much work it could save you. And there's even a free beta available.
- Chris Klug created a simple [OpenXML library for Silverlight](http://chris.59north.com/post/OpenXML-2b-Silverlight-using-a-little-library.aspx). You could check if it does what you need and then try porting it to WinRT since the source is available.